# Formatting timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formatting, timestamp

How do you format Rails timestamps in a more human-readable format? If I simply print out `created_at` or `updated_at` in my view like this:

```
<% @created = scenario.created_at %>
```

Then I will get:

2009-03-27 23:53:38 UTC

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-strftime) (from Ruby's Time) and [`to_formatted_s`](http://apidock.com/rails/Date/to_formatted_s) (from Rails' ActiveSupport) functions should be able to handle all of your time-formatting needs.

Comment: Thanks for that. But it seems to only work in the console and not in my Rails views.

Comment: Can you give a fuller example of the code you're using in the view?  It appears to work as expected in my view tests.  Where/how are you displaying @created?

Comment: @GregCampbell: a fuller example: `@comment.created_at.strftime("%d %b %y") #Output: 05 Jul 10`. Source: http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/23-rails-date-formats

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the I18n functionality. It allows you to do the following in your views:

```
<%= localize(scenario.created_at, :format => :long) %>
```

where the formats are defined in your locales.
[More info](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1a93e93d1b26a73ed3707b27059542d6efa2cd04/actionpack/lib/action_controller/translation.rb#L8)

Answer (score 8):

Also

```
<%= l scenario.created_at, :format => :sample) %>
```

And in locales/en.yml(depending of language)

```
  en:
    time:
      formats:
        sample: '%d.%m.%Y'
```

To learn more, see - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: This is a clean, and elegant solution

Comment: This follows rails guides. Our solution ten years ago, and even now.

Answer (score 4):

Time.now().to_i    works great. For reverse conversion use Time.at(argument)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strftime` to format the timestamp in many ways. I prefer [`some_data[:created_at].strftime('%F %T')`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime). `%F` shows "2017-02-08"    (Calendar date extended), and `%T` shows "08:37:48" (Local time extended).

For timezone issues, add this lines to your `config/application.rb` file

```
config.time_zone = 'your_timezone_string'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

Answer (score 0):

See below for **1.Make a timestamp** and 2.Format a timestamp

**1.Make a timestamp**

This line code in Ruby `Time.now.getutc` returns a UTC time stamp e.g. `2022-07-05 15:20:40.976321 UTC`.

**2.Format a timestamp**

You can then format it with strftime. The 2 lines of code:

```
timestamp_UTC=Time.now.getutc 

timestamp_UTC_formated=timestamp_UTC.strftime("%Y%m%d_%Hh%Mm%Ss")
```

return a timestamp formated, e.g. `"20220705_15h23m24s"`.

*See strftime documentation for the formatting syntax.*

Answer (score -1):

you have to modify the timestamp file, in my case this file is located in `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb`. You must search for this line:

```
self.class.default_timezone == :utc ? Time.now.utc : Time.now
```

and change it to this:

```
self.class.default_timezone == :utc ? Time.now.utc : Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
```

The trick is to modify the format with the `strftime` method, you can change the format if you want.

Now rails will use your format to update the "updated_at" column.

Comment: Changing the source code is not the way to do this. You can use formatters in your own code to get the same results. When you update Rails, the change you proposed would be lost.